# How to check notification accessibility service is enabled or not by user in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, accessibility

How to check notification accessibility service is enabled or not by user in android ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);`
```

I have tried this code but this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code to check weather your service is running or not:

```
    public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Activity activity) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (NotificationService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It will return true if service is running currently otherwise its return false.